# How to rename objItem.Name in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to move printers on the local machine from an old print server to a new print server. If I keep the printer names the same my code works. But if I want to rename a printer at the same time I was trying to reset the value of objItem.Name. In the below code, how can I rename objItem.Name inside my select Case statement?

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim strComputer, DefaultPTR 
Dim objWMIService, colItems, WshNetwork
Dim LogFile
Dim wshShell
CONST ForWriting = 2
CONST ForAppending = 8

Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
UserProf = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERPROFILE%" )
LogFile = UserProf & "\MovePtrsToNewPrintServerName.txt"

If (objfso.FileExists(UserProf & "\MovePtrsToNewPrintServerName.txt")) Then
  'WScript.Echo("File exists!")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(LogFile, ForWriting)
End If

strComputer = "."
DefaultPTR=0

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer",,48) 

For Each objItem in colItems

  If UCase(Left(objItem.Name,21)) = "\\OldPrintServerName\" Then
    If objItem.Attributes And 4 Then 
      DefaultPTR = 1
    End If

    objItem.Name.Delete_ 


    Select Case UCase(objItem.Name)

     Case "\\OldPrintServerName\HP4000"
      objItem.Name.Rename "\\OldPrintServerName\HPP3005"    '<--- I know this doesn't work so
                                                            ' how can I rename objItem.Name to
                                                            ' the new printer name?

    End Select

    WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\NewPrintServerName\" & Right(objItem.Name,Len
    (objItem.Name) - 9)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 then
      objFile.WriteLine "Problem with " & Right(objItem.Name,Len(objItem.Name) - 21)
      Err.Clear
    End if
    If DefaultPTR = 1 then
      WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\NewPrintServerName\" & Right(objItem.Name,Len
      (objItem.Name) - 21)
      DefaultPTR = 0
    End If
  End If

Next 

objFile.WriteLine "Printers have been moved from OldPrintServerName to NewPrintServerName"
```

Comment: The `Win32_Printer` class has a [RenamePrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. `objItem.RenamePrinter "<new name>"` should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. I'm not just trying trying to rename a printer. I'm trying to move several to a new print server and just rename some at the same time. I am really trying to change the value of objItem.Name so the rest of the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the RenamePrinter method is available for use. I've updated your code below to accomodate the command.

Specifically:

```
    Select Case UCase(objItem.Name)
     Case "\\OldPrintServerName\HP4000"
      objItem.RenamePrinter("HPP3005")
    End Select
```

Also, you need to differentiate between the Printers Name and the ShareName. The ShareName is what is displayed in the network browser when a user goes to the print server directly.

So to configure the sharename, rather than the printer name, it would be:

```
For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    objPrinter.ShareName = "HPP3005"
    objPrinter.Put_
Next
```

---

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim strComputer, DefaultPTR 
Dim objWMIService, colItems, WshNetwork
Dim LogFile
Dim wshShell
CONST ForWriting = 2
CONST ForAppending = 8

Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
UserProf = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERPROFILE%" )
LogFile = UserProf & "\MovePtrsToNewPrintServerName.txt"

If (objfso.FileExists(UserProf & "\MovePtrsToNewPrintServerName.txt")) Then
  'WScript.Echo("File exists!")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(LogFile, ForWriting)
End If

strComputer = "."
DefaultPTR=0

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer",,48) 

For Each objItem in colItems

  If UCase(Left(objItem.Name,21)) = "\\OldPrintServerName\" Then
    If objItem.Attributes And 4 Then 
      DefaultPTR = 1
    End If

    objItem.Name.Delete_ 


    Select Case UCase(objItem.Name)
     Case "\\OldPrintServerName\HP4000"
      objItem.ShareName = "HPP3005"
      objItem.Put_
    End Select

    WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\NewPrintServerName\" & Right(objItem.Name,Len
    (objItem.Name) - 9)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 then
      objFile.WriteLine "Problem with " & Right(objItem.Name,Len(objItem.Name) - 21)
      Err.Clear
    End if
    If DefaultPTR = 1 then
      WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\NewPrintServerName\" & Right(objItem.Name,Len
      (objItem.Name) - 21)
      DefaultPTR = 0
    End If
  End If

Next 

objFile.WriteLine "Printers have been moved from OldPrintServerName to NewPrintServerName"
```

And here's an article detailing the method->[HERE](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/08/how-can-i-use-a-script-to-rename-a-printer.aspx)

Comment: Hello Rich, thanks for your response. I will have to look at the scripting guys article and try to understand better. Using your modified code, if I put a wscript.echo objItem.Name right after the Select Case statement, it still comes out as \\OldPrintServerName\HP4000 instead of \\OldPrintServerName\HPP3005.

Comment: Right, because we renamed the file the printer is stored under, so since this is a networked printer, I've updated your code above to rename the SharedName. Please try out the updated code above and let me know.

Comment: Hello Rich, I'm sorry but I'm still getting the same result. Again, if I put a wscript.echo objItem.Name right after the End Select, it still comes out as \\OldPrintServerName\HP4000 instead of \\OldPrintServerName\HPP3005.  Thank you for your assistance. I know there has to be a way to modify the name property of the objItem.

Comment: Well, the objects were queried, then you iterated through them, then you set the sharename, then you msgbox'd an objects submethod.....Ofcourse it's not going to show the update. The objects are not live data feeds. You should re-run your program and see if the printers have changed anyway.